# Why is the result of the gourl.ParseQuery method so unexpected?

Tags: go

The result of this program is `{"x":["1 1 3"], "y":["2", "3"]}`.
But why is not `{"x":["1+1+3"], "y":["2", "3"]}`?
What do I need to do to get the expected result`"1+1+3"`?

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    m, err := url.ParseQuery(`x=1+1+3&y=2&y=3`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(toJSON(m))
}

func toJSON(m any) string {
    js, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return strings.ReplaceAll(string(js), ",", ", ")
}
```

Sandbox: https://go.dev/play/p/o0TiRTVpaQk

`{"x":["1+1+3"], "y":["2", "3"]}`

Comment: You need to escape the `+` character in query

Comment: `x=1+1+1` in an URL query means x has the value `1 1 1`. If this is intended to be `1+1+1` then either your query is not properly encoded or this is not an URL query at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url.ParseQuery` replaces `+` with

relevant code fragment:

```
        case '+':
            if mode == encodeQueryComponent {
                t.WriteByte(' ')
            } else {
                t.WriteByte('+')
            }
```

the solution is to encode `+` (replace them with `%2B`)

like so:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    m, err := url.ParseQuery(`x=1%2B1%2B3&y=2&y=3`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(toJSON(m))
}

func toJSON(m any) string {
    js, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return strings.ReplaceAll(string(js), ",", ", ")
}
```